# How to remove un-necessary line spaces from paragraph

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a situation. I am trying to extract text from pdf/image using tesseract. The input text from pdf/image is in below format :

```
Review

Dear All,

Turning The Corner On A
Challenge full Year (This is a heading)
We are executing and gaining
mobile share in our markets
in Australia against intense competition.
However, the past year was
```

After reading this through tesseract, I am getting output in below format :

```
Review
    
Dear All,
    
Turning The Corner On A
Challenge full Year (This is a heading)
We are executing and gaining
mobile share in our markets

in Australia against intense competition.
However, 
the past year was
```

I want the output in below format :

```
Review
    
Dear All,
    
Turning The Corner On A
Challenge full Year (This is a heading)
We are executing and gaining
mobile share in our markets
in Australia against intense competition.
However, the past year was
```

I tried to execute below command to get expected result, but it did not work.

```
"".join([s for s in result.splitlines(True) if s.strip("\r\n")])
### result is variable to store my tesseract output
```

The above code removed all the linespaces from paragraph and below is the output:

```
Review
Dear All,
Turning The Corner On A
Challenge full Year (This is a heading)
We are executing and gaining
mobile share in our markets
in Australia against intense competition.
However, the past year was
```

Comment: `"".join([s for s in result.splitlines(True) if s.strip("\r\n")])` is giving the desired output with Py 3.x

Comment: This code is removing all the necessary linespace as well. I want to keep linespace after "Review" and "Dear All,". Is there any way to keep those?

Comment: You can use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) for this problem.  Do not select any newline character which is not preceded by 'Dear all' or something like that. That will depend on you dataset

Comment: If you are not very familiar with them, you can use [this](https://regex101.com/) to practice and test your required regular expressions.

Comment: Yes, it is done using regular expression!! Thanks a lot.